# std::out_of_range error accessing a std::string in C++

Tags: c++, outofrangeexception

I am part of a team of three moderate-aptitude programmers, and we are currently attempting to write a program in C++ to embody our new encryption algorithm.  However, we have encountered an error which indicates that we are surpassing the length of a string, at some point.  I have tried debugging this, myself, but I have had no luck.  It's in the jumble() function, though ...

Anyway, here's a paste of our sourcecode with a temporary main() function:
http://pastebin.com/GvvYAsKg

It compiles fine, but upon running, we get the following error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
>      what(): basic_string::substr
>      Aborted

Comment: Would you please re-indent the code properly and paste it over here?

Comment: As almost an aside: what makes you think that writing your own encryption function is a good idea?

Comment: Moderate programmers as opposed to militant programmers?

Comment: Philip, it's for an engineering class project.  Everybody is supposed to design something.  Our team decided to do an encryption algorithm.

Comment: n.m., I should have said moderately-skilled.  We aren't the most experienced programmers, but we're not completely novice, either.

Comment: If you don't know how to use a debugger then you are a complete novice. Sorry.

Answer (score 7):

One of your problems is in this line:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ( inPT.length() + 1 ); i++)
```

This will mean you attempt to access `inPT[inPT.length]` which is one character beyond the end of the string. You want

```
for(int i = 0; i < inPT.length(); i++)
```

or possibly to be using a more idiomatic C++ construct like `std::for_each` so you can't make this kind of fencepost error. As noted in the comments, running this in a debugger would have pointed this out to you pretty quickly.

Comment: Or the new C++11 range-base for loop: `for (char c : inPT) { ... }`

Comment: This was also causing the problem.  Both your answer and John's were correct!  Many thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Presumably this piece of code

```
if(modCount >= inPT.length())
{
    modCount = 0;
}
int mod = inKey.at(modCount);
```

is meant to read

```
if(modCount >= inKey.length())
{
    modCount = 0;
}
int mod = inKey.at(modCount);
```

Your guard on an out of range access on `inKey` is using the wrong variable.